# I can't update status by use the checked box

Tags: codeigniter

Please help i can't update the status by use the checked box. 
When i selected the check box and select delete button, status will change to 'deleted' but now i can't update the data.

This is my view

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="delete" class="myButton" >Delete</a>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" class="cb_invoice" id="<?php echo $r->INVOICENUMBER;?>" value="<?php echo $r->INVOICENUMBER;?>">
</div>
```

This my script

```
<script>
$('#delete').click(function() {
            var _url = "<?php echo site_url('commission/delete_invoices');?>"; 
            var d_obj = $(".cb_invoice");
            var d_val = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < d_obj.length; i++){
                if(d_obj[i].checked){
                    d_val.push(d_obj[i].value);
                }
            }
            $.ajax({
              url: _url,
              data: {data: d_val},
              type: 'post',
              success: function(data) {
                //console.log(data);
                location.reload();
              }
            });             
         });
</script>
```

This my controller

```
function delete_invoices(){
    $invoice = $this->input->post('data');
    foreach ($invoice as $invoice) {
        $this->m_commission->delete_invoice($invoice);
    }
}
```

This is my model

```
function delete_invoice($invoice){
    $this->db->update('salesinvoiceheader');
    $this->db->set('STATUS','deleted');
    $this->db->where('INVOICENUMBER', $invoice);
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `$invoice = $this->input->post('data');`??

Comment: It's get the id send data to controller page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the order of update as follows in your modal:-

```
function delete_invoice($invoice){
    $this->db->set('STATUS','deleted');
    $this->db->where('INVOICENUMBER', $invoice);
    $this->db->update('salesinvoiceheader');
}
```

Comment: This does't make any change in query!!